# Update Whole Document in MongoDb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, lokijs

I am trying to insert and update document in mongodb using node.js. I can successfully insert the document using the following code.

```
var obj = { jsonit: 
            { users: {},
              groups: {},
              meta: 
                  { id: 'daf09a36-b961-3db4-3144-aa19479c70c7'},
              name: 'John Doe',
              meta: undefined,
              loki: undefined
           }
Collection.insert( obj ).then( function insertCollectioncb(object) {
        obj = object;
      });
```

After that i want to update the whole document as i don't know which keys will be change or which new keys will be inserted. I am using following code to update my document.

```
var obj = jsonit: 
       { users: {},
         groups: {},
         meta: 
             { id: '0da70a1f-f5cd-0fd2-10c8-7aa421296057'} ,
        name: 'John Doe',
        creationDate: '2016-10-13T11:05:08.453Z',
        income: 1000,
        meta: null,
        loki: null 
      }
Collection.update( { _id: '57ff860b240e9d50a42ec53c' }, obj ).then( function updateBranchcb(object) {
        obj = object;
      });
```

I can do it successfully in mongo shell but can't do it through node js.

Comment: Do you get an error message or anything?

Comment: The obj definition is not well formed on the second code.

Comment: @DaveV no i am not getting any error

Comment: @MiguelGonzalez sorry it was typo in question i have fixed it. actually i am not creating those variable by myself i just mentioned them here so people can have a better idea what my object actually looks like

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var obj = jsonit: 
       { users: {},
         groups: {},
         meta: 
             { id: '0da70a1f-f5cd-0fd2-10c8-7aa421296057'} ,
        name: 'John Doe',
        creationDate: '2016-10-13T11:05:08.453Z',
        income: 1000,
        meta: null,
        loki: null }, true
Collection.update( { _id: '57ff860b240e9d50a42ec53c' }, obj ).then( function updateBranchcb(object) {
        obj = object;
      });
```

The problem is an extra close curly brace

```
 meta: 
    { id: '0da70a1f-f5cd-0fd2-10c8-7aa421296057'} },
```